# Call requires API level 17 (current min is 15): android.app.Fragment#getChildFragmentManager

Tags: java, android

I get the above error message when trying to pass through the getChildFragmentManager() method within new FragmentPagerAdapter. My current minSDK is 15

I have tried the following: 
- Install API 17
- Increasing the minSDK

But still no joy, anyone have any idea why or had the similar issue?

```
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()) {
        @Override
        public android.support.v4.app.Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }
    });
```

Comment: You have increased the minSDK inside of your gradle build file or at what exactly position?

Comment: would be good to see the gradle & and the code

Comment: I have tried to increase the minSDK from 15 to 18, when I leave the minSDK at 18 i dont get the error message anymore. However, i do get a message saying FragmentPagerAdapter cannot be applied to android.app.FragmentManager

Comment: Well, does that mean that sdk level 17 did not work? For the other problem, I think you need to use the SupportFragmentManager. (just FYI, this is a very good article: https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html)

Comment: Ahhh just got it to work. I also tried to use SupportFragmentManager but that also didnt work. To get it to work, I noticed the extended Fragment class was imported from 

import android.app.fragment;

so I changed it to the below

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;